# Registering custom element in Dart lang

Tags: dart

I've the below custom element, and I want to register it in the same file

custombtn.dart:

```dart
class SubmitFonix extends HtmlElement {

  String name;

  factory SubmitFonix([String name]) => (new Element.tag(tag) as SubmitFonix)
       ..name=name
      ;

  SubmitFonix.created() : super.created() {
  ...
}
```

currently, I'm registering the element in the main function, as this:

```dart
void main() {
  document.registerElement(SubmitFonix.tag, SubmitFonix);
 }
```

I wanted to add the registration line to the custombtn.dart file, instead of having it in the main() function, but if I could not!

in polymer.dart, I noticed they are using below statement:

```dart
@initMethod
upgradePaperFocusable() => registerDartType('paper-focusable', PaperFocusable);
```

and in other file they have:

```dart
const initMethod = const InitMethodAnnotation();

class InitMethodAnnotation {
 const InitMethodAnnotation();
}
```

so, tried using the same concept, and updated my custom element file to be as:

```dart
    class SubmitFonix extends HtmlElement {

  String name;

  factory SubmitFonix([String name]) => (new Element.tag(tag) as SubmitFonix)
       ..name=name
      ;

  SubmitFonix.created() : super.created() {
  ...
}
@initMethod
upgradeCustomBtn() => document.registerElement(SubmitFonix.tag, SubmitFonix);
```

at execution, I got this this error in the console:

```dart
Exception: type 'HtmlElement' is not a subtype of type 'SubmitFonix' in type cast.
submit_btn.dart:10
SubmitFonix.SubmitFonix.
```

submit_btn.dart:10 is: factory SubmitFonix([String name]) => (new Element.tag(tag) as SubmitFonix)

any thought?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@initMethod` is a Polymer annotation and you can only use it if you use Polymer and I assume you do not. If you move the `registerElement` away from main you have it to put to a function or method which is called directly or indirectly from main.

Comment: Thanks @Gunter, your comment along with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26821567/custom-annotation-metadata-in-dart-lang/26830363#26830363 and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826521/executing-bundle-of-functions-by-their-metadata-tag-in-dart-lang helped me solving the issue