# Dart: how to get metadata for anything other than classes and class members?

Tags: dart, metadata, dart-mirrors

I am experimenting with metadata.

In this document :

https://www.dartlang.org/guides/language/language-tour#metadata

It is said that:

> Metadata can appear before a library, class, typedef, type parameter,
>   constructor, factory, function, field, parameter, or variable
>   declaration and before an import or export directive. You can retrieve
>   metadata at runtime using reflection.

Thus... I try to get metadata...

```
// Resources:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826521/executing-bundle-of-functions-by-their-metadata-tag-in-dart-lang

import 'dart:mirrors';

/// This class represents the metadata "OnFailure".
class OnFailure {
  final int criticalityLevel;
  final String handlerName;
  /// Constructor.
  /// [criticalityLevel] represent the level of criticality.
  /// [handlerName] represents the name of the function to execute.
  const OnFailure(int this.criticalityLevel, String this.handlerName);
}

/// This class represents the metadata "Log".
class Log {
  final String destination;
  const Log(String this.destination);
}

/// This class represents the metadata "Doc".
class Doc {
  final String path;
  const Doc(String this.path);
}

@OnFailure(0, 'onFatalHandler')
class ClassProcessor {
  @Doc('/var/doc/ClassProcessor')
  bool status;

  @Log('/var/log/ClassProcessor')
  bool call(int value) {
    return value > 0;
  }
}

@OnFailure(0, 'onFatalHandler')
typedef bool TypeProcessor(int value);

main() {

  ClassProcessor processorClass = ClassProcessor();

  // Get the metadata for a class.
  InstanceMirror instanceMirror = reflect(processorClass);
  ClassMirror classMirror = instanceMirror.type;
  print(instanceMirror.type.metadata); // => [InstanceMirror on Instance of 'OnFailure']
  OnFailure metadata = classMirror.metadata[0].reflectee;
  print("Critical level: ${metadata.criticalityLevel}"); // => Critical level: 0
  print("Handler name: ${metadata.handlerName}"); // => Handler name: onFatalHandler

  // Get the metadata for a method.
  MethodMirror methodMirror = classMirror.declarations[Symbol('call')];
  Log log = methodMirror.metadata[0].reflectee;
  print("Log file is ${log.destination}");

  // Get the metadata for a property.
  VariableMirror variableMirror = classMirror.declarations[Symbol('status')];
  Doc doc = variableMirror.metadata[0].reflectee;
  print("Doc file is ${doc.path}");

  // Get the metadata for a typedef.
  // ???
  TypeProcessor processorInstance = (int value) {
    if (value > 0) {
      print("That's OK.");
    } else {
      print("A fatal error occurred !");
    }
  };

  instanceMirror = reflect(processorInstance);
  instanceMirror.type.declarations.forEach((Symbol symbol, DeclarationMirror declarationMirror) {
    print(declarationMirror.metadata);
  });

  // Get the metadata for a variable.
  // ???
  @Doc('/var/doc/data')
  int data = 10;

  instanceMirror = reflect(data);
  print(instanceMirror.reflectee); // => 10
  instanceMirror.type.declarations.forEach((Symbol symbol, DeclarationMirror declarationMirror) {
    print(declarationMirror.metadata);
  });
}
```

I can get metadata for classes, class properties and class methods, but I can't do so with "typedef" and for a variable.

Any idea on how to get metadata for anything other than a class or a class member ?

Comment: Click on the dart-mirrors tag I just added and you'll find a lot of examoles.

Comment: Well, I had already read a lot of the material presented in this link. I took 8 hours to read more and experiment more. I did not find out how to get the metadata from a `typedef`. My co-workers tried to find out also... with no result either. The documentation says that we can do it. However, what we understand by looking at all the responses is that it is not possible. That's too much trouble for us. We give up on Dart.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a Dart bug.

With

```
  var mirrorSystem = currentMirrorSystem();
  var libraryMirror = mirrorSystem.libraries.keys
      .where((k) => k.path.endsWith('/bin/main.dart'))
      .map((k) => mirrorSystem.libraries[k])
      .first;
```

`libraryMirror.declarations` should include `typedef`s, but it doesn't.