# How do I create a custom element in dart?

Tags: web, dart, element

I am trying to make a custom element in dart.  It should simply contain 2 buttons.  It never actually makes it through the construction process...what am I doing wrong?

```
class GraphButton extends Element {
  factory GraphButton() => new Element.tag('GraphButton');
  ButtonElement colorBtn;
  ButtonElement removeBtn;

  GraphButton.created() : super.created() {

  }

  void setup(String buttonText) {
    text = buttonText;
    //initialize color btn
    colorBtn
      ..id = 'colorBtn' + text
      ..text = "colorSelector"
      ..onClick.listen(
          (var e) => querySelector('#output').text = id + 'button clicked!');

//initialize remove button
    removeBtn
      ..id = 'removeBtn' + text
      ..text = 'X'
      ..onClick.listen(
          (var e) => this.remove());

  //add to DOM
  this.children
  ..add(colorBtn)
  ..add(removeBtn);
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem? I don't have time just now to have a closer look but there are similar questions with answers here on SO already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few issues in your code.

- Custom elements need to follow the naming rules that they need to have a `-` in their name
- The element needs to be registered in order for the browser to be able to instantiate them
- The `setup(...)` method you added wasn't called, therefore not caption was added to the button
- Custom elements need to extend `HtmlElement`

[**DartPad example**](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/09c8ab74a851fcf46cc203ae1dabc827)

See also:

- [Registering custom element in Dart lang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26820844/registering-custom-element-in-dart-lang)
- [extendTag in Dart custom element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26314402/extendtag-in-dart-custom-element)

Comment: Fixed everything.  Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Would you mind accepting the answer to make it clear your problem is solved (by clicking the checkmark below the up and downvote buttons. Thanks.

Comment: This apparently doesn't work when in the context of tests, because the `registerElement` method seems to be disabled. Do you guys have the same problem?

Comment: What fo you mean with "disabled" perhaps the browser API changed. Custom Elements do have changed quite a bit since but I haven't used that Dart since then.