# How to test (TDD) an `HtmlDocument` in Dart?

Tags: html, web, dart, tdd

## 1. The Problem

I'm trying to create a browser extension in Dart. Currently, I'm using the [`webext`](https://pub.dev/packages/webext/versions/0.1.0) package, which basically emulates the typical JS environment in Dart.

In the `main()` function of `content.dart` file, I wish to manipulate the DOM. The `document` variable is available and is of type `HtmlDocument`, which comes from [`dart:html`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.0/dart-html/dart-html-library.html). This is all well and good, but how would you create a testing harness with that, considering `HtmlDocument` doesn't have a public constructor?

## 2. What I've tried so far

I've tried to use the parent of `HtmlDocument`, i.e., `Document`. Something like this for a custom HTML tag:

```dart
import 'dart:html';

void main() {
  final Document document = Document();
  document.registerElement(CustomElement.tag, CustomElement);
  document.createElement(CustomElement.tag);
}

class CustomElement extends HtmlElement {
  static const String tag = 'custom-tag';

  factory CustomElement.created() => null;
}
```

But the `Document` class doesn't have the necessary API and registering custom tags is not supported apparently — the `supportsRegisterElement` getter gives me back `false`, which might be related to Chrome or Dartium, I'm not sure.

Comment: Oh, wait, the library itself initializes the `document` (`HtmlDocument`) for you? I'm going to check if the one provided in the test file is enough. [This other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37092473/4756173) has some valuable information.

Comment: Neither `document.registerElement` nor `window.customElements.define` work somehow. See [this issue](https://github.com/dart-lang/co19/issues/673).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know why creating a custom `HtmlElement` isn't working in this case, but there's a good enough way around the overall problem: [`DomParser`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.9.2/dart-html/DomParser-class.html).

You can use the `parseFromString` method to parse an HTML string into a `Document` and use it as a simplified way to test your code. The `DomParser`'s behavior emulates the its JS counterpart: [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser).

An example:

```dart
import 'dart:html' show Document, DomParser, Element;

import 'package:test/test.dart' show expect, test;

void main() {
  const String htmlAsString = '<p>A paragraph</p>';
  
  final Document document = DomParser().parseFromString(htmlAsString, 'text/html');
  
  test('Checking the text inside the paragraph', () {
    final Element paragraph = document.querySelector('p');
  
    expect(paragraph.text, 'A paragraph');
  });
}
```

Note that using `dart:io` to open the HTML fixtures/fakes/mocks won't be possible because most of its functionalities aren't supported by the browser.

Custom tags can also be used in the stringed HTML above, they won't have custom classes, they will all be of runtime type `HtmlElement`, which is a subclass of `Element`. The parser will be able to handle them by changing/initializing their `tagName`s in the background — it actually basically seems to do this for all tags.